# click events for dynamic array of buttons

Tags: android

with the below code i can generate an array of button.but i cant specify the click events for these button.how can i do these

```
Button addAsFriend[] = new Button[c.getCount()];
 for( i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)
 {
    addAsFriend[i] = new Button(this);
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Button addAsFriend[] = new Button[c.getCount()];
 for( i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)
 {
    Button btn = new Button(this);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
        // your code here
       }
     };);
    addAsFriend[i] = btn;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Button addAsFriend[] = new Button[c.getCount()];
for( i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)
{
 addAsFriend[i] = new Button(this);
 ((Button)addAsFriend[i]).setOnClickListener(myclickListener);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) Interface in you activity. Doing this you will have to override the onClick() method. Then you can pass the activity as an OnClickListener to each button.

```
public class YourActivity implements OnClickListener {

     public void onCreate(){
         ...

         Button addAsFriend[] = new Button[c.getCount()];
         for( i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)
         {
             addAsFriend[i] = new Button(this);
             ((Button)addAsFriend[i]).setOnClickListener(this);
         }    
        ...
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        // Put your listener code here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

...And if you want to retrieve the index of that button then use a map!

```
Map<View,Integer> buttonMap = new HashMap<View,Integer>();

Button addAsFriend[] = new Button[c.getCount()];

for( i=0;i<c.getCount();i++)
{
   Button btn = new Button(this);
   buttonMap.put(btn,i);

   btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
         int index = buttonMap.get( v );

         // do something with index here

      }
   };);
   addAsFriend[i] = btn;
}
```